# equipo.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

tengo problemas con una prueba, estoy tratando de mostrar datos de un servicio REST con reactjs y me muestra este error
[image: Error]

Este es el codigo que estoy utilizando

```js
import './App.css';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [equipo, setEquipo] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function obtenerDatos(){
      const data = await fetch('https://0q27loouph.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/');
      const users = await data.json();
      setEquipo(users);
    }
    obtenerDatos()
  }, []);


  return ( 
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Pacientes</h1>
      <ul>
        {
          equipo.map(item => (
            <li key = {item.name}>{item.name} - {item.email}</li>
          ))
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

De antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: que es lo que te retorna la función `data.json()` ??

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta seguramente en lo que devuelve;

```
const users = await data.json();
```

no es un arreglo, puedo que sea un objeto json, o otra cosa, asi te recomentaria hacer un

```
console.log(users)
```

y de este modo saber que te llega y formatear la información para que sea un arreglo, todo esto dentro del useEffect, suerte.